# Why doesn't this RegEx work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the text "foo" between the two brackets in this following statement:

> Expected [foo] but Recieved [__]

I'm then trying to replace the text with "...".   When I run the following code I get an invalid grouping error in JavaScript.  When I run the expression in Regexr it works the way I expect it to.

```
var text = $("#assertion").html().replace( /(?<=Expected \[).*(?=\] )/,"...");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bittersweetryan/VcraW/

Comment: You can solve this problem by not using lookbacks.  Just include the lookback text in the regex as regular text to match with parens around it and then use `$1` in your replacement string to put it back into the replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript regexes don't understand lookbacks (the `?<=`). You need to match the `Expected [` part explicitely:

```
replace(/(Expected \[)[^\]]*/, "$1...")
```

The $1 is to avoid retyping the "Expected [" part and I changed the rest of the regex a bit to avoid greedy matching with `.*`

http://jsfiddle.net/VcraW/2/

Comment: +1 for the 25 seconds you were faster and having exactly the same thoughts than me.

Answer (score 3):

Because javascript does not support look behind assertions.

You can work around by putting this in a capturing group and using this in the replacement

```
.replace( /(Expected \[).*(?=\] )/,"$1...");
```

The content of the first pair of brackets is stored in the capturing group 1 and you can get this back using `$1`